# Can I count on order being preserved in a Python tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I've got a list of datetimes from which I want to construct time segments.  In other words, turn `[t0, t1, ... tn]` into `[(t0,t1),(t1,t2),...,(tn-1, tn)]`.  I've done it this way:

```
# start by sorting list of datetimes
mdtimes.sort()
# construct tuples which represent possible start and end dates

# left edges
dtg0 = [x for x in mdtimes]
dtg0.pop()

# right edges
dtg1 = [x for x in mdtimes]
dtg1.reverse()
dtg1.pop()
dtg1.sort()

dtsegs = zip(dtg0,dtg1)
```

Questions...

1. Can I count on tn-1 < tn for any (tn-1,tn) after I've created them this way?  (Is ordering preserved?)
2. Is it good practice to copy the original `mdtimes` list with list comprehensions?  If not how should it be done?
3. The purpose for constructing these tuples is to iterate over them and segment a data set with `tn-1` and `tn`.  Is this a reasonable approach? i.e.

   ```
   datasegment = [x for x in bigdata if ( (x['datetime'] > tleft) and (x['datetime'] < tright))]
   ```

Thanks

Comment: btw: `(x['datetime'] > tleft) and (x['datetime'] < tright)` is `(tleft < x['datetime'] < tright)`

Comment: The question that you didn't ask: Given `x` is sorted, is  `x.reverse(); x.pop(); x.sort()` a good idea? Answer: **NO**; it's horrid; `x.pop(0)` will do the same thing, and in any case just about any of the answers is better than using the `pop()` method.

Comment: I ended up going with `dtsegs = zip(mdtimes[:],mdtimes[1:])`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Tuple order is as you insert values into the tuple. They're not going to be sorted as I think you're asking. `zip` will again, retain the order you inserted the values in.
2. It's an acceptable method, but I have 2 alternate suggestions: Use the [copy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) module, or use `dtg1 = mdtimes[:]`.
3. Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 22):

Both `list` and `tuple` are ordered.

```
dtg0, dtg1 = itertools.tee(mdtimes)
next(dtg0)
dtsegs = zip(dtg0, dtg1)
```

Comment: Does this have any advantage over Pawel's implied suggestion of `dtsegs = zip(mdtimes[:],mdtimes[1:])`

Comment: @Pete: It doesn't involve creating 2 temporary lists.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve the same with `zip`:

```
>>> l = ["t0", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6"]
>>> zip(l[::2], l[1::2])
[('t0', 't1'), ('t2', 't3'), ('t4', 't5')]
```

Comment: to keep it continuous I used `zip(l[:],l[1:])`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of: `dtg0 = [x for x in mdtimes]`, `dtg0 = mdtimes[:]` would do, since you just copy one list into another. Note: starting with Python 3.3, you can just say `newlist = oldlist.copy()`

As for order, `zip`'s order is well defined, and both lists and tuples are ordered collections, so you should have no problem here.

Comment: `list(mdtimes)` is another way to copy, IMHO the cleanest of them.  list() is a constructor, so it always creates a new object, even when its argument is already a list.

Comment: @Beni: it's a question of idioms and what people are used to. Some mentally process `[:]` as copying a list. By the way, there's a proposal underway to add a `copy` method to a list object, so the above becomes `mdtimes.copy()`. It's discussed in this Python issue: http://bugs.python.org/issue10516

Comment: Cool!  You've landed `list.copy()` and `list.clear()` in python 3.3.  I think `.copy()` is my new favorite style.

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin: right, I should probably update this answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

Turning [x1, x2, x3, ...] into [(x1, x2), (x2, x3), ...] is called a **pairwise combination**. [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) documentation provides a recipe:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

for ta, tb in pairwise(mdtimes): 
    ....
```

Answer (score 3):

**This is an answer to the question "Is this a reasonable approach?" (which appears to have been ignored by all).**

**Summary:** You may want/need to lift your gaze from making a pairwise thingy out of `mdtimes` to the encompassing problem (segmenting `bigdata`).

**Detail:**

The desired use of the result is expressed as:

```
datasegment = [x for x in bigdata if ( (x['datetime'] > tleft) and (x['datetime'] < tright))]
```

which is better expressed as:

```
datasegment = [x for x in bigdata if tleft < x['datetime'] < tright]
```

Note that as that stands, it will not include any cases where the timestamp is exactly equal to one of the boundary points, so let's change it to:

```
datasegment = [x for x in bigdata if tleft <= x['datetime'] < tright]
```

But that's going to appear in a loop:

```
for tleft, tright in dtsegs:
    datasegment = [x for x in bigdata if tleft <= x['datetime'] < tright]
    do_something_with(datasegment)
```

Whoops! That's going to take time proportional to `len(bigdata) * len(dtsegs)` ... what are likely values of `len(bigdata)` and `len(dtsegs)`?

If `bigdata` is sorted, what you want to do can be done in time proportional to `N`, where `N = len(bigdata)`. If `bigdata` is not already sorted, it can be sorted in time proportional to `N * log(N)`.

You might like to ask another question ...

It's also worth pointing out that any items in `bigdata` that have a timestamp < min(mdtimes) or >= max(mdtimes) will not be included in any data segment ... is this intentional?

Comment: Thanks John... mileage varies but `bigdata` is on the order of 10^6 records and there are about 5-10 useful segments with about 10^5 records in each segment.  `bigdata` is not sorted per se but it is read from an alphabetized sequence of files which have the date as part of the name, so portions are sorted by datetime.  Yes, some data intentionally left out if it does not fall in one of the segments.  The time bottleneck thus far is reading the text files(500MB+ for each analysis), creating the datetimes and zipping the selected data columns.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert, but aren't you quadrupling your memory requirements by copying the list and then making a new list of pairs taken from two lists? Why not just do the following:

```
dtsegs = [(dtg0[i], dtg0[i+1]) for i in range(len(dtg0)-1)]
```

Dunno how "Pythonic" that is, though.

EDIT: Actually, looking at what you need to do with this list of tuples, you could just do this [i] and [i+1] stuff directly at that level and not even create this new structure at all. I don't know how many dates you're dealing with, though - if it's some small number I suppose it doesn't really matter.

For what it's worth, a couple of the other answerers here seem to be misunderstanding your question, though I can't comment on their posts since I don't have enough reputation yet :) Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's solution seems the best to me, though his "next(dtg0)" should probably be "next(dtg1)" (?)

Comment: Personally I would rather have a separate structure with the date segments to make the subsequent code easier to understand.  Also it allows me to view the segments to make sure everything is OK.